# Filtering array of objects with lodash on Angular

Tags: angular, filter, nested, lodash

I work on Angular 7 and I'd like to apply several filters on a list of objects i receive from my back end.
The objects are of a type I call "CV". 
Inside CV are other objects such as described below.

```js
CV {
  employee: Employee;
  certifications: Certification[];
}
Employee {
  empId: number;
  empAgency: string;
  empBu: string;
}
```

My main problem is that I need to filter the list of CV according to the properties of the nested objects.

I got inspired a lot by this tutorial to apply multiple filters: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/multi-property-data-filtering-with-firebase-and-angular-4/.

I tried something like this in the typeScript..

```js
  employees: CV[];
  filteredEmployees: CV[];
  //array I use to filter
  filters = {};
  
  //properties I wanna filter by
  empAgency: string;
  empBu: string;
  //standard entry to delete a filter property value
  private DefaultChoice: string = "DefaultChoice";
  
   private applyFilters() {
    if (this.filteredEmployees.length === this.employees.length) {
      this.filteredEmployees = _.filter(this.filteredEmployees,     _.conforms(this.filters));
    } else {
      this.filteredEmployees = this.employees;
      this.filteredEmployees = _.filter(this.filteredEmployees, _.conforms(this.filters));
    }
  }
filterExact(property: string, property2: string, rule: any) {
    if (rule ==='DefaultChoice') {
      delete this.filters[property][property2];
      this.filters[property] = [];
      this.filters[property][property2] = null;
    }
    else {
      this.filters[property] = [];
      this.filters[property][property2] = val => val === rule;
    }
    this.applyFilters();
  }
```

But it doesn't work with the nested properties. My problem is that I don't understand how to correctly pass to my function the property of the nested object.

Anyone could help?

By helping, I also include any other suggestion on how to chain multiple filters on nested objects in Angular (with/without lodash). I'm still rather a newbie in this field, so feel free to point me towards the good direction!

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] of your issue on https://stackblitz.com so that people can help you. Reading your question now makes me realize it's hard to process, there's a lof of useless information or business information that we will not use to answer you.

Comment: why use underscore and not typescript's default array filter() ?

Comment: @trichetriche hank you for your suggestion. I'm rather new to Stackoverflow as well, so I didn't know I needed to post on stackblitz, I'll do it asap. However I wouldn't say my exemple is very verbose, the REAL code is much bigger and the objects much more complex. I wanted to give a clear idea of my thought process, and how I have an actual code which worked and at which point it doesn't work any more.

Comment: @Stavm because from what I gathered, chaining filters with filter() would imply a certain order: you apply the first one, your map the result, you apply the second one,etc.. in my case, I'd like to have a fully reversible stack of filters I can apply. I want to start from no matter which filter, and cancel the filter property if I go back to my default value. However, if you think it's easier with filter(), please point me towards a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Following the example you linked, I don't think you need to pass both properties to `filterExact()`. I think you just need to write additional filter functions to perform whatever 2nd-level filtering you're trying to accomplish:

```
  filterExactAgency(property: string, rule: any) {
    this.filters[property] = val => val == rule
    this.applyFilters()
  }

  filterExactBusinessUnit(property: string, rule: any) {
    this.filters[property] = val => val == rule
    this.applyFilters()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Yes, I may want to split the filter in many filters, However, my problem is that I don't fully understand how to properly indicate to my filter to look for the nested properties with the method I used.

Comment: As it is, `applyFilters()` will already apply multiple filters with properties from the various filter functions. If you're just wondering academically how to do it, I believe it would look like a combination of `applyFilters()` and `filterExact()`.

Comment: No it doesn't actually if you take my snippets as they are now, they don't work. they worked as long as filterExact() took a a parameter a direct property (i.e. empAgency). Now I need to feed it something like employee.empAgency, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because when you say `filters[property]` You are adding `{ property: property }` to the filters object. But if you say `filters[property][property2]` you are adding `{ property: property: { property2: property2 } } to the object, which isn't what you want.

Comment: What happens if you say `filters[property, property2]` ?